# Failed to monitor agent

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have enabled the Recording and analytics behavior option to monitor real-time and post-call analytics but when I try to live monitor the agent but it shows me an error "Failed to monitor agent".

I want to monitor the real-time metrics of the agent in Amazon Connect.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.